# Generalizing from a specific type to a class in a GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt, rank-n-types

I have the following definitions

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeInType, RankNTypes #-}
import Data.Kind

class Character (a :: * -> *) where
  showVal :: a b -> b -> String

data ExampleCharacter a where
  Variable :: ExampleCharacter String
  EqualSign :: ExampleCharacter ()
  Deref :: ExampleCharacter ()

instance Character ExampleCharacter where
  showVal Variable = id
  showVal EqualSign = const "="
  showVal Deref = const "*"

data Symbol :: forall a. ExampleCharacter a -> * where
  Terminal :: a -> Symbol (b :: ExampleCharacter a)
```

as you can see I have defined a Symbol class that uses ExampleCharacters in the type signature. Example usage would be `let sym = Terminal "xyy" :: Symbol Variable` creating a variable symbol with the name `"xyy"`.

Now, the obvious next step would be to generalize `ExampleCharacter` to `Character c`. I tried the following:

```
data Symbol :: (forall c (a :: *). Character c) => c a -> * where
  Terminal :: a -> Symbol (b :: c a)
```

But I get the following error:

```
main.hs:22:20: error:
    • Illegal constraint in a type: forall (c :: * -> *) a. Character c
    • In the type ‘Symbol (b :: c a)’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘Terminal’
      In the data declaration for ‘Symbol’
```

I'm not quite sure what the error wants to tell me. Why is `forall (c :: * -> *) a. Character c` an illegal constraint and how so? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Move the constraint to the constructor. E.g. `data Symbol :: c a -> * where { Terminal :: Character c => a -> Symbol (b :: c a) }`

Comment: @Alec that worked. I'm not quite sure why it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#constraints-in-kinds):

> As kinds and types are the same, kinds can now (with -XTypeInType)
>   contain type constraints. **Only equality constraints are currently
>   supported, however.** We expect this to extend to other constraints in
>   the future.

So in principle what you've written is sensible; it simply isn't supported yet (as of writing, most recent GHC is 8.2.2).