# How do I extract type information from Proxy in a type family for a GADT?

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families, proxy-pattern

I have the following snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}

import Data.Proxy

data Foo where
  FooInt :: Foo
  FooProxy :: IsEnum e ~ True => Proxy e -> Foo

type family IsEnum e :: Bool

type family FromFoo (foo :: Foo) where
  FromFoo FooInt = Int
  FromFoo (FooProxy ('Proxy :: Proxy e)) = e
```

The general idea is that I'm trying to use `Foo` as a data kind where I could do

```
type MyFoo1 = FooInt :: Foo
type instance IsEnum Bool = True
type MyFoo2 = FooProxy ('Proxy :: Proxy Bool) :: Foo
```

and ensure that the proxied type being passed to `FooProxy` is a part of the `IsEnum` type family (I can't just do `FooProxy :: Enum e => Proxy e -> Foo` because [only equality constraints are currently supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331898/8565175)).

But when I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
<interactive>:30:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected kind ‘'True’ with actual kind ‘IsEnum e’
    • In the first argument of ‘FromFoo’, namely
        ‘(FooProxy ( 'Proxy :: Proxy e))’
      In the type family declaration for ‘FromFoo’
```

The problem is when I want to convert from my `Foo` type to the concrete type in `FromFoo`, I want `FooProxy` to evaluate to the proxied type. So I'm trying to pattern match on `Proxy` to return the proxied type `e`, but then it seems to be checking the `IsEnum e ~ True` constraint again. I would think that the constraint would only be checked when *creating* a `FooProxy` value, but it seems to be checking again when *pattern matching*.

Comment: Here's an idea. Are you sure you're not writing a `IsEnum` instance for the `Bool` _type_ only? In your case you want the instance for the `Bool` _kind_.

Comment: I don't understand how that plays a role. The first snippet alone errors, before running anything in the second snippet.